# Filter many2many [tags] field based on a Project id in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to filter tags for each project_id.
Model structure is as below:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    _name = "project.task"


    project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project', string='Project',
        compute='_compute_project_id', store=True, readonly=False,
        index=True, tracking=True, check_company=True, change_default=True)
```

Inherited model structure:

```
class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    _inherit = "project.task"

    product = fields.Many2many('adv.project.products', string="Product", tracking=True)


class ProductsVariants(models.Model):
    _name = "adv.project.products"

    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)
```

and My view.xml file is:

```
<field name="product" domain="[('id', 'in', project_id)],"/>
```

and It shows the below error:

```
ValueError: Invalid domain term ('id', 'in', 1)
```

Can anyone pls help me to implement correct filter procedure in odoov14. TIA

Answer (score 1):

When using `in` operator, [value](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-domains) should be a list of items:

> `in`
> is equal to any of the items from value, value should be a list of items

Use `[('project_id', '=', project_id)]` instead

**Note**:
*`project_id` should be a many2one field that references a project in `adv.project.products`* model

Comment: when I use '=' it doesn't show any error but it only returns Single tag. But I am expecting all the Tags.

Comment: Do you have the ``project_id`` field declared in the `adv.project.products` model?

Comment: Ah okay, I haven't actually. 
So I need to copy the project_id definition as it is from 'project.task' model?

Comment: In the domain above, you are filtering tags where the tag id is equal to the project id and this is not what you want. To filter the tags, you need to use `[('project_id', '=', project_id)]`, the `project_id` should be a field in the `adv.project.products` model.

Comment: I got your point, and added 'project_id' Many2one filed inside 'adv.project.products' . But strangely it does not save the project_id. Now I am clueless why it's happening. Any suggestions pls

Comment: Does each task has its own product variants? If so, use a one2many field and define a reference (inverse name) to the task in the variant model  and it will be filled automatically then you can use the following domain in the `product` field: `<field name="product" domain="[('inverse_id', '=', id)]"/>`. If you want to keep the project field in variant model and set it automatically when you want to add a new variant, pass the project in in the context as follows: `context="{'default_project_id': project_id}"`